# ConstraintLayout strange constraint lines

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I'm using a constraint layout, as i understood it would make the UI look similar on different screen sizes. The problem is that I cannot drag a constraint line from a calendat view to a textView

So therefor I created the constraint line I needed using

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/appfortday"
```

picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecxY9.jpg

and it created this weird wiggly line instead of a nomral zig-zag line. What is the difference between these lines? Will it behave as a normal constraint line?

here is a part of my xml:

```xml
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textcalender"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/appfortday"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textcalender" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appfortday"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Appointments for today"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/feelingsrec"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calendarView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.49" />
```

I would like to know the difference between these lines and if it would affect the way my UI will look on different screen sizes.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "wiggly" line indicates, that the two views have constraints pointing at each other.

`calendarView` has a constraint to the top of `appfortday` and vice versa.

This is OK. If you have views which have constraints that point at each other, you can change how they are aligned by adding [chain styles](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain).

Comment: Is there a webpage that you can reference for what all the zigzag/wiggly/straight lines mean?

Comment: @AlanSTACK I can only refer you to the link in the answer above. The paragraph ["Adjust the view size"](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#adjust-the-view-size) explains the different lines which represents view sizes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and answering on a weekend!